# CSS footer in theory

Tags: css, browser, footer, standards-compliance

I know there are 1001 CSS footer hacks out there that require multiple contortions in order to satisfy even the oldest browser.

But I would like to know how a footer can be made for a modern standard-compliant browser. I expected the following code to work, but it doesn't - the footer is not at the bottom of the page but directly below the "content". Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Footer Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body
        {
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #page
        {
            position: relative; /* <--- relative position for footer's parent */
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #AAA;
        }
        #header
        {
            height: 3em;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: #F00;
        }
        #content
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: #0F0;
        }
        #footer
        {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0; /* <--- distance from #footer's bottom to #page's bottom  */
            height: 3em;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: #00F;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <p>This is the header!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Yeah, some content!</p>
            <p>Yeah, some content!</p>
            <p>Yeah, some content!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>This is the footer!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Clarification: I want the footer to be at the bottom of the **viewport**. So if there is little content there should be a gap below the content, and the footer should be at the bottom of the page. But if there is much content scrollbars should appear, and the footer should become only visible when one scrolls down.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #footer
        {
            position: fixed;
            width:100%;
            bottom: 0; /* <--- distance from #footer's bottom to #page's bottom  */
            height: 3em;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: #00F;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, longer content doesn't push that fixed footer down.

Comment: position:fixed will always positions with respect to screen hence it will position at the bottom of the screen irrespective of the content

Comment: Yes, but that's not the kind of footer I want to achieve. I edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

here you can find some code as follows

Add the following lines of CSS to your stylesheet. The negative value for the margin in .wrapper is the same number as the height of .footer and .push. The negative margin should always equal to the full height of the footer (including any padding or borders you may add).

**In CSS:**

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
    html,body
    {
        height: 100%;
        }
        .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -4em;
        }
        .footer, .push {
        height: 4em;
        }
```

Follow this HTML structure. No content can be outside of the .wrapper and .footer div tags unless it is absolutely positioned with CSS. There should also be no content inside the .push div as it is a hidden element that "pushes" down the footer so it doesn't overlap anything.

**In HTML Body:**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>

      <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2013</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Something is missing in the CSS section at top

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why the original version didn't work...

But the following code is hack-free and seems to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Footer Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html 
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body 
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #page 
        {
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute; 
            background-color: #AAA;
        }

        #header 
        {
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: #F00;
        }

        #content 
        {
            margin-bottom: 5em; /* <--- footer's height */
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: #0F0;
        }

        #footer 
        {
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #00F;
        }

        #footer > *
        {
            padding: 1em; /* <--- additional rule for footer's content */
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { $("button").click(function() { $("#hidden").slideToggle(1000); }) });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <p>This is the header!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Yeah, some content!</p>
            <p>Yeah, some content!</p>
            <p>Yeah, some content!</p>
            <button>Push the footer!</button>
            <div id="hidden" style="display: none">
                <p>Begin of extra content</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>Much hidden content!</p>
                <p>End of extra content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>This is the footer!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I don't like about it:

- The content needs to know the footer's height.
- Additional rule required for footer's content.